# Is indexing efficient in IList when using array?

Tags: arrays, .net, interface

In .NET, arrays implement the `IList` (or `IList<T>`) interface. How efficient is it to access array items through this interface opposed to directly accessing the array itself?

Comment: I believe it will box if you use it with value types, so it will bring regression, but would work the same for reference types. `IList<T>` works as efficient as `T[]`.

Comment: I'm looking at this and thinking that Eric Lippert's [Performance Rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) is relevant, particularly 2-4 - "Do you really need to answer that question?", "Is that really the bottleneck?" and "Is the difference relevant?"

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Thank you, I did not consider boxing when using generics. I am mostly using reference types. @Damien_The_Unbeliever some good points in the link to consider. I mainly want to use `IList` since I want to avoid having my colleges and I convert big arrays/lists to lists/arrays when passing them to methods and such.